# Delegation and MetaClass in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented

We have an OOP course at our university, while discussing the concepts I came across MetaClass and Delegation. As far as I know, these don't exist in C++.

Could someone give an example by which I can better understand how to simulate them instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delegation can be achieved in C++ by using functors (made even more simple to declare in C++11 with lambdas). Any type can define a call operator member function, so you could say that C++ does have Delegation, just not in an easy syntax, but fixed with lambdas.

To be more precise (see comments), lambda don't act as delegate, functors - that are simply objects you can call like function and therefore move around until you need to call them - act as delegates. Lambdas expressions are just syntactic sugar allowing to define "in place" a functor directly in the code that will use it. [Look in the wikipedia page for lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) for an introduction, it's the same as in C# or Python but a bit more powerful because you can put more than one-liners in.

MetaClass is harder but not impossible : [look for reflection libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application) for similar features. However, it's very rare that such features are really useful in C++ as you can [read there the reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359237/why-does-c-not-have-reflection). Most of the time, RTTI is enough.

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to how lambdas act as delegates?

Comment: Lambda don't act as delegate, functors - that are simply objects you can call like function and therefore move around until you need to call them - act as delegates. Lambdas are just syntactic sugar allowing to define "in place" a functor directly in the code that will use it. Look in the wikipedia page for lambda for an introduction, it's the same as in C# or Python but a bit more powerful because you can put more than one-liners in.